# How do I make my if else statement continue?

Tags: c

C beginner here. I was wondering how I can get my program to print the last line "Your total is..." without having to enter another key. After the question "How many orders" is answered, the last printf statement in my code doesn't display without me entering another key. Hope you can help, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char choice;
    int quantity;
    int price;

    printf("###############\n");    
    printf("##a Burger 50##\n");
    printf("##b Hotdog 30##\n");
    printf("##c Fries  20##\n\n");
    printf("Hello, may I take your order please?\n\n");
    printf("Please select the letter of your order.\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    if (choice = 'a') {
        printf("How many orders?\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &quantity);
        price = quantity * 50;
    } else if (choice = 'b') {
        printf("How many orders?\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &quantity);
        price = quantity * 30;
    } else if (choice = 'c') {
        printf("How many orders?\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &quantity);
        price = quantity * 20;
    }

    printf("Your total is %d, checkout in cashier.\n", price);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Remove the newline `\n` from every `scanf` statement's format string.

Comment: `=` is assignment; `==` is to comp[are, so `if (choice == 'a') {...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem with your format specifiers:

```
scanf("%d\n", &quantity);
```

The `\n` in the format string causes `scanf` to wait until a newline is entered **and** some other character after that.  That's why you have to enter some other key.  Remove the newline and you'll be able to input values without having to enter something extra:

```
scanf("%d", &quantity);
```

Also, this isn't doing what you think:

```
if (choice = 'a') {
    ...
} else if (choice = 'b') {
    ...
} else if (choice = 'c') {
```

In C `=` is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator.  When you do an assignment, the value of the expression is assigned value.  So the first `if` assigns `'a'` to `choice`, then that value is evaluated in a boolean context.  Because the value is not 0, it will always be true and so you'll never enter either of the other two cases.

For comparisons, you want the `==` operator:

```
if (choice == 'a') {
    ...
} else if (choice == 'b') {
    ...
} else if (choice == 'c') {
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\n` from `scanf("%d\n", &quantity);` so it looks like this:

```
scanf("%d", &quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @dbush covers all the issues! However, for the sake of completeness, here's an edited/corrected/annotated version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char choice;
    int quantity;
    int price;

    printf("###############\n");
    printf("##a Burger 50##\n");
    printf("##b Hotdog 30##\n");
    printf("##c Fries  20##\n\n");
    printf("Hello, may I take your order please?\n\n");
    printf("Please select the letter of your order.\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    if (choice == 'a') { // NOTE: a == b COMPARES a with b whereas a = b ASSIGNS b to a.
        printf("How many orders?\n");
        scanf("%d", &quantity); // Don't expect scanf to read in a TERMINATING \n!
        price = quantity * 50;
    }
    else if (choice == 'b') { // Vide supra!
        printf("How many orders?\n");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        price = quantity * 30;
    }
    else if (choice == 'c') { // Vide supra supra!
        printf("How many orders?\n");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        price = quantity * 20;
    }
    printf("Your total is %d, checkout in cashier.\n", price);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, runs and works!

Comment: Recommendation: Upvote the answer from @dbush (as I have done)! Copy/paste my answer, if you want. If you downvote my answer, I'll probably delete it.

Comment: Congratulations for your fairness.